# A small problem about the dependence of 3 random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X_0,X_1,X_2$ be 3 random variable with given joint density $f^{(X_0,X_1,X_2)}$. Let $(Z_t)$ be a stochastic process independent from $X_1,X_2,X_3$ with a given density $f^{Z_t}$.

I am interested in the density of $(X_0+X_1+X_2 + Z_t, X_0,X_1,X_2)$. Can we express it using $f^{(X_0,X_1,X_2)}$ and $f^{Z_t}$ ?

Comment: Use the fact that $(X_0+X_1+X_2 + Z_t, X_0,X_1,X_2)=(X_0+X_1+X_2 , X_0,X_1,X_2)+(Z_t,0,0,0)$ and the the two terms in this sum are independent.